# How to select the output device of audio in ubuntu manually?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

In Ubuntu, we can select the output device of audio in *sound preferences*. But now I want to write a shell script, so I need to select the output device from the commandline.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can first view your current default audio device by typing:

```
pactl stat
```

And with

```
pactl list
```

you can view all your devices.

And with this command

```
echo "set-default-sink alsa_output.Headset" | pacmd
```

you can set the default device.

But I found a much better source for this problem and a included little shell script for this problem here http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1370383.html

Comment: Nowadays `pactl stat` shows 
`Currently in use: 95 blocks containing 721,4 KiB bytes total.
Allocated during whole lifetime: 103649 blocks containing 420,9 MiB bytes total.
Sample cache size: 0 B`

Comment: Looks like the simple stats have been moved from `pactl stats` to `pactl info`.